# Specific value frequency across multiple c

Tags: r

I've data set contains 1000s columns and every 7 rows were grouped as group1,group2 and so on.., i trying to get all 0's count* with 2 and all 1's are just count. Finally i also need to get total frequency of both.

```
 group <- c("group1","group2","group3")
 col1 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,NaN,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NaN,1,0,0,0)
 col2 <- c(1,NaN,0,NaN,1,NaN,1,1,0,1,1,NaN,0,NaN,1,NaN,1,1,0,1)
 col3 <- c(0,1,NaN,NaN,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,NaN,NaN,0,0,0,0,0,1)
 
 expected output is

         col1   col2    col3
 group1  0.75   0.625   0.9
 group2  0.93   0.7     0.8
 group3  0.8    0.6     0.92
```

I would appreciate your to great help, thanks

Comment: @akrun, all cols have 20 (incl. NaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do

```
t(sapply(split(df1[-1], df1$group), \(x) {
  zero_sum <- colSums(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
 one_sum <- colSums(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
  ((zero_sum * 2) + one_sum)/((zero_sum + one_sum)*2)} ))
```

-output

```
         col1  col2      col3
group1 0.7500000 0.625 0.9000000
group2 0.9285714 0.700 0.8000000
group3 0.8000000 0.600 0.9166667
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
"group2", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", 
"group3", "group3"), col1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NaN, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NaN, 1, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(1, NaN, 0, NaN, 1, 
NaN, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NaN, 0, NaN, 1, NaN, 1, 1, 0, 1), col3 = c(0, 
1, NaN, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, NaN, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: thank you for prompt suggestions, i also need to multiply with 2 for all 0's count             and add 1's count to it. How can i include additional step? Can i please have your suggestion?

Comment: There is Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `col1` <double> and `col5097` <character>.
---
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ungroup
 8. tidyr:::pivot_longer.data.frame(...)
 9. tidyr::pivot_longer_spec(...)

Comment: @Gopi Probably one of the `col` is having a different type in your original data.  You may convert all of them to `character` and then do pivot_longer i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with('col'), as.character)) %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%...`

Comment: @Gopi or use `values_transform = as.character` as in my update

Comment: @akun, it works, but few things still needed,. NA should not be counted in total (here just 0,1,2 counts *2) , and sum (0s*2 and 1s).                                                                     For ex., col1 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,NaN,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,NaN,1,0,0,0) should have 0s count*2 = 24, 1s count = 6, sum of 0s+1s=24+6=30; total = except NaN *2 = 36

Comment: @Gopi Have you checked the code `values_drop_na = TRUE` which removes the NAs?

Comment: @akun, yes i tried update code as above. Still it's not producing the way i wanted.

Comment: @Gopi You haven't showed your expected output based on the input you showed.  So, it is not clear

Comment: sorry for the confusion!, the expected output added in main question. The final result derived from frequency (0s)*2 + frequency (1s) / sum(frequency of all values)*2 except NaN.